# Pyramid Cherrpy blank error page

Tags: error-handling, pyramid, cherrypy

I have a small Pyramid application that by default used the waitress web server when I set it up. However I am now trying to switch to CherryPy since it works much better with sse.

But for uncaught exceptions I got a 500 error page with content in waitress, but using cherrypy the pages are just blank (the status is correctly 500 though).

The only thing I did to switch was to change the line:

```
use = egg:waitress#main
```

to

```
use = egg:pyramid#cherrypy
```

In the [documentation](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/_cperror.html#unanticipated-errors) for CherryPy I can read that I can set a custom error message for an unanticipated error. Tried that out but I saw no effect at all, the function is never called - I even tried to add a breakpoint to CherryPy's internal error response but it was not hit either.

I suspect something else is wrong though since I assume CherryPy should show "something" by default for a 500 page ?

Comment: Show us a stack trace or a way for us to replicate the issue then maybe we can give you an answer. Easiest way is to start with the starter template from Pyramid, and tell us what to change to replicate what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attempted to reproduce the issue using the `starter` scaffold that comes with Pyramid, and made the following modification to the existing `views.py` that it comes with:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPInternalServerError


@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
def my_view(request):
    raise HTTPInternalServerError()
```

On both CherryPy and waitress this returns a page with the `HTTPInternalServerError()` on it including the text.

Changing the raise to:

```
raise ValueError('test')
```

However only shows something on the page if the `pyramid_debugtoolbar` is enabled, and the user accessing the URL is allowed to see the `pyramid_debugtoolbar` (this is controlled by the `hosts` setting for `pyramid_debugtoolbar`).

CherryPy does not have its own text. Unfortunately I don't see a way to use the `_cp_config` method of enabling custom error messages, as there is no way to set it up on the HTTP server that is used when using the `CherrypyWSGIServer` which is used by the Pyramid `cherrypy` entrypoint used by pserve.

What you can do, is set up a default exception view in Pyramid such as the following:

```
@view_config(context=Exception)
def exception_view(request):
    request.response.status = 500
    request.response.text = u'Something went very wrong. Sorry!'
    return request.response
```

You can off course customise this exception view however you'd like. If this exception view raises however, you will be at the mercy of CherryPy who will serve you a blank page.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. At first it did not appear to work - the same blank page as before. However it turned out that the line that set the text generated: _You can only set Response.text to a unicode string (not )_. So changing it to: u'Something went wrong' worked, I'll modify your answer with that.

Comment: Sorry @Zitrax, I use Python 3, and all strings are unicode.

Comment: Right, I am still stuck on 2.7 with this. The 'u' prefix should work for both though.

Comment: Yep, no worries :-). Was simply explaining why I didn't have it on there.